isometries and unitary operators, Specht theorem
I was looking at the properties of the trace operator $\operatorname{tr}$, in particular the properties of the trace regarding isometric conjugation. 
We say that $T\in \mathcal{H}$ is an isometry if $T^*T=\mathbb{I}$, we say that $U \in \mathcal{H}$ is unitary if it is an isometry and $UU^*=\mathbb{I}$. Let $M\in\mathcal{H}$, the conjugate of $M$ by $T$ is $TMT^*$. 
Now $\operatorname{tr}(M)=\operatorname{tr}(TMT^*)$ since the trace is cyclic, moreover $\operatorname{tr(|M|)=\operatorname{tr}(|TMT^*|)}$ $\forall M\in B(\mathcal{H}),T \in \mathcal{H}$ isometry(Trace norm is invariant under conjugation by an isometry). 
Now this two properties together(in reality only the first one should suffice but I was interested also in trace norms) should imply that $\forall \text{words } W, \operatorname{tr}(W(M,M^*))=\operatorname{tr}(W(TMT^*,TM^*T^*))$ infact everytime we multiply $TMT^*$ and $TM^*T^*$ the inner $T^*T$ simplifies and the outer $TW(M,M^*)T^*$ simplifies by trace ciclicity. 
Now Specht theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specht%27s_theorem) tells me that if $\forall \text{words } W, \operatorname{tr}(W(A,A^*))=\operatorname{tr}(W(B,B^*))$ then $B$ and $A$ are unitarily equivalent. Now setting $B=TAT^*$  we have that $\forall \text{words } W, \operatorname{tr}(W(A,A^*))=\operatorname{tr}(W(TAT^*,TA^*T^*))$ but $A$ and $B=TAT^*$
are NOT unitarily equivalent because T is just an isometry. 
The question now is simple: what am I doing wrong?
$$ $$
PS a word $W(A,A^*)$ is basically one of the possible combinations of the products of $A$ and $A^*$ so for example $AAA^*AA^*=A^2A^*AA^*$ is a word, $AA^*A^{10}$ is a word,$(A^*)^{25}$ is a word etc...

I think Specht's theorem simply does not hold in infinite dimensions, and in finite dimensions, every isometry is unitary.

Neither result is true in infinite dimension (your second statement is simply a particular case of the first). Here is an example: let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and
$$
Ax=\Big(\frac{x_1}2,\frac{x_2}4,\frac{x_3}8,\ldots\Big),\qquad\qquad
Bx=\Big(0,\frac{x_2}2,\frac{x_3}4,\frac{x_4}8,\ldots\Big).
$$
Then $A,B$ are positive, with trace $1$, and $\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=\operatorname{tr}(B^n)$ for all $n$. But $A$ is injective and $B$ is not, so they are not unitarily equivalent.
Here $B=SAS^*$, where $S$ is the unilateral shift.

What do you mean with unilateral shift? Because for example if $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)$, $R$ is the right shift operator ie $Rx=(0,x_1,x_2,...)$, then it seems to me that $B=RA$ infact if $Ax=(\frac{x_1}{2},\frac{x_2}{4}...)$, then $RAx=(0,\frac{x_1}{2},\frac{x_2}{4}...)$. I think that if S were the right shift R, then B should be $Bx=(0,\frac{x_2}{2},\frac{x_3}{4}...)$. This that you made was a really good example, because basically doing $RAR^*$ is like shifting the matrix A in the diagonal($A=diag(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},...),B=diag(0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},...)$) which means equal moments

Yes, I had a typo in the definition of $B$.
